# servo motor s curve motion

Tags: embedded, microcontroller

I am trying to control a Industrial AC Servo motor using my XE166 device.

The controller interfaces with the servo controller using the PULSE and DIRECTION control.

To achieve a jerk-free motion I have been trying to create a S Curve motion profile (motor speed v/s time).

Calculating instantaneous speed is no problem as I know the distance moved by the motor per pulse, and the pulse duration.

I need to understand how to arrive at a mathematical equation that I could use, that would tell me what should be the nth pulses duration to have the speed profile as an S-Curve.

Since these must be a common requirement in any domain requiring motion control (Robotics, CNC, industrial) there must be some standard reference to do it

Comment: maybe add a tag for the programming language and API you use? did you already try googling for the answer, and check on wikipedia? sounds like the answer should also be in one or several papers. do you have access to a university network where you can search for papers (research publications)?

Comment: sigmoid or logistic curve equations look like a good starting point.

Comment: Infineon and other manufactures of such MCUs/drivers. published a lot of information on that. Some include the mathematics and some even software approaches. Have you actually search for any?

Answer (score 0):

Step period is the time difference between two positions one step apart on the motion curve.  If the position is defined by X(T), then the step time requires the inverse function T(X), and any given step period is P = T(X+1) - T(X).  On a microcontroller with limited processing power, this is usually solved with an approximation - for 2nd order constant acceleration motion, [Atmel has a fantastic example using a Taylor series approximation for inter-step time (Application note AVR446)](http://www.atmel.com/images/doc8017.pdf).

Another solution which works for higher order curves involves root solving.  To solve T(x0), let U(T) = X(T) - x0 and solve for U(T) = 0.

For a constant acceleration curve, the quadratic formula woks great (but requires a square root operation - usually expensive on microcontrollers).  For jerk-limited motion (a 3rd degree polynomial minimum) the roots can be found with an [iterative root solving algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root-finding_algorithm).